# Nested if statement and logic with strings in csv file in R

Tags: r, nested-loops

I have a csv file that looks like this:

[image]

I try to create an algorithm that goes like this:

```
Iterate through each row; 
If the condition is Success, 
      if T1 == P1, increase score one point 
      if T2 == P2, increase score one point
      if T3 == P3, increase score one point 
Else if the condition is Failure,
      elif T1 != P1, increase score one point 
      elif T2 != P2, increase score one point
      elif T3 != P3, increase score one point
```

However, I got stuck on 2 things:

- When I say something like:

  for (i in 1:4){
  if (data[i,7] == "Success")
  .......
  There is a syntax problem because of using string with logic. How to get it right?
- It doesn't calculate correctly when I state something like:         if(data[i,1] == data[i,4]) {score = score+1}, but it does calculate correctly if I use numbers instead of letters in the csv file. Again, how to use strings with logic operators?

3. The other problem is using nested if statements. How to do it so I can use the algorithm above?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the example data with the expected output

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Answer (score 2):

We may also do this with `across` i.e. loop `across` the columns that `starts_with` 'T', then inside the loop, get the column names (`cur_column()`), replace the substring 'T', with 'P', and `get` its value, do a logical comparison, convert to numeric index by adding 1 (as `R` indexing starts from 1) to replace the values in vector (`c(-1, 1)`) based on the position index, and finally do a `rowSums` on the `across` output to create the 'total_score' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
    mutate(total_score = rowSums(across(starts_with('T'), 
     ~ c(-1, 1)[1 + (. == get(str_replace(cur_column(), 'T', 'P')))])))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  T1    T2    P1    P2    total_score
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>       <dbl>
1 a     b     a     a               0
2 a     a     a     a               2
3 a     a     a     b               0
4 b     a     b     b               0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(T1 = c("a", "a", "a", "b"), T2 = c("b", "a", "a", 
"a"), P1 = c("a", "a", "a", "b"), P2 = c("a", "a", "b", "b")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

a `case_when` structure can be used for your wish. Since we don't know how your data structure is,  I created a dummy data which represents yours;

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1453)

scores <- data.frame(T1=sample(1:5,size = 200,replace = T),
                    T2=sample(1:5,size = 200,replace = T),
                    T3=sample(1:5,size = 200,replace = T),
                    P1=sample(1:5,size = 200,replace = T),
                    P2=sample(1:5,size = 200,replace = T),
                    P3=sample(1:5,size = 200,replace = T),
                    score=sample(50:100,size = 200,replace = T))

scores2 <- scores %>%
mutate(new_score=case_when(T1==P1 ~ score + 1,
         T2==P2 ~ score + 1,
         T3==P3 ~ score + 1,
         TRUE ~ score - 1)) 


scores2%>%
head
```

Note: TRUE, means otherwise;

**output;**

```
     T1    T2    T3    P1    P2    P3 score new_score
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>     <dbl>
1     4     2     2     1     5     5    64        63
2     3     5     4     2     1     3    82        81
3     5     1     5     4     5     5    89        90
4     2     5     3     4     5     1    62        63
5     3     5     4     3     2     4    53        54
6     3     1     4     1     3     2    82        81
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your work! How about "Success" and "Failure" Conditions? Can I also put them in case_when?

Answer (score 0):

If I got the problem right, each row is an observation, so I will compare each T column with the respective P column, than create a score for each comparison, finally I can sum them for each row.

### Libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
```

### Example Data

```
df <-
  tibble(
    T1 = c("a","a","a","b"),
    T2 = c("b","a","a","a"),
    P1 = c("a","a","a","b"),
    P2 = c("a","a","b","b")
  )
```

### Code

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    S1 = if_else(T1 == P1, 1,-1),
    S2 = if_else(T2 == P2, 1,-1)
  ) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(total_score = sum(c_across(starts_with("S"))))
```

### Output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 7
# Rowwise: 
  T1    T2    P1    P2       S1    S2 total_score
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
1 a     b     a     a         1    -1           0
2 a     a     a     a         1     1           2
3 a     a     a     b         1    -1           0
4 b     a     b     b         1    -1           0
```